# Is the ternary operator (?:) thread safe in C#?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, ternary-operator

Consider the following two alternatives of getting the higher number between `currentPrice` and `100`...

```
int price = currentPrice > 100 ? currentPrice : 100

int price = Math.Max(currentPrice, 100)
```

I raised this question because I was thinking about a context where the `currentPrice` variable could be edited by other threads.

In the first case... could `price` obtain a value lower than `100`?

I'm thinking about the following:

```
if (currentPrice > 100) {
    //currentPrice is edited here.
    price = currentPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not threadsafe.

`?:` is just shortcut for normal `if`, so your `if` sample is equivalent to `?` one - you can get price lower than 100 if there is no locking outside this code.

Comment: Contrary answer in few minutes? :D

Comment: @dotNETbeginner :) Good observation. when I read my first answer I wanted to give me -10 too.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, currentPrice is read twice. Once for comparison, once for assignment.

In practice, the compiler may cache the access to the variable. I don't know about C# but in C++ on x86:

```
MOV AX, [currentPrice]
MOV BX, 100 ;cache the immediate
CMP AX, BX
JLE $1      ;if(currentPrice > 100){
MOV AX, BX
$1:         ;}
MOV [BP+price], AX ;price is on the stack.
```

The same load-once optimisation happens in Java bytecode unless currentPrice is declared volatile.

So, in theory, it can happen. In practice, on most platforms, it won't, but you cannot count on that.

Answer (score 3):

Not a specialist in C#, but even var++ is not thread save, since may translated to from reading into/writing from register in assembly.

Ternary operator is far more complicated. It has 3 parts, while each part can be endlessly big (e.g. call to some function). Therefore, it's pretty easy to conclude that ternary operator is not thread safe.

Comment: +1; I'm afraid x86 won't let you `INC`rement a memory location, so it _will_ be translated as a move to registry / increment / move to memory combo.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, it might be cached but the language does not require it.

You can use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx) if you need lock-free threadsafe assignments. But given the example, I'd go for a more coarse grained locking strategy.