# Why Convert String to Int32 fails randomly in Website

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I have some piece of code which fails at times due to error `System.FormatException`. In my understanding if the `UserId` is not empty then default `0` should be returned from below method `GetUserProperty` and I know (and have not doubt on this) that `UserId` in the system will be either some number or empty, it will never be anything non-numeric.

Code as below:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var userId = Convert.ToInt32(GetUserProperty("UserId", "0"));
    // Do something with userId..
}

public string GetUserProperty(string propertyName, string defaultValue = "")
{
    var propertyValue = SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty(propertyName);
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue) ? propertyValue : defaultValue;
}
```

StackTrace in the system log says:

`System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at ...`

Comment: What `GetUserProperty("UserId", "0")` returns exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: ` Convert.ToInt32()` is not capable of handling `null`

Comment: @un-lucky But `GetUserProperty` never returns null...

Comment: One of the possibilities is *integer overflow* - the code works for *short ids*  (e.g. `123`) but fails when the value is *long enough* (e.g. `1234567890`).

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(string)` never fails if the input is a string representing a valid integer - so it can't fail randomly. You need to find out why `GetUserProperty("UserId", "0")` isn't a valid integer representation.

Comment: @un-lucky: `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0 if you pass in a `null` reference. However, it won't handle an *empty* string.

Comment: @JackHughes Look closely: he passes "0" as explicit default value. If it's null or whitespace, it'll handle a "0" which should return 0 as userId.

Comment: `int num = Convert.ToInt32("");`  result in error

Comment: @JonSkeet - https://dotnetfiddle.net/cGJv0R it handles an empty string fine... Looking at what he wrote, unless UserId is a non-numeric value... there's no reason for it to fail.

Comment: there's no conversion happening in the fiddle.

Comment: @Phill No, It's not http://goo.gl/eYj4lR

Comment: @Phill: Yes, but that's not calling `Convert.ToInt32` with an empty string, is it?

Comment: Reason of asking this question is that it is very weird since this code should not fail ideally. Only one thing I can think of as area of improvement in this code is making this thread-safe, since this is ASP.NET is this code thread-safe ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Based on the sample code, he passes in the default value of "0", if the value pulled out is null or empty, it will use the default value... So unless the pulled out value is anything other than a number. It will not fail... The fact the default value on the method signature is empty string is a bug.

Comment: @Leonel i donno what you're sending me.

Comment: @Phill: Yes, but neither un-lucky nor I were talking about that. We were *only* talking about the `Convert.ToInt32` call involved. Please look at the comments: "Convert.ToInt32()` is not capable of handling null" and "Convert.ToInt32 returns 0 if you pass in a null reference. However, it won't handle an empty string."

Comment: @Phill Sorry, I'm just telling you that `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(one)?:`is not the problem, the topic is about string converting to `Int32`.

Comment: @JonSkeet https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdNRc4 simulating his SecurityUtil returning an empty string. How is his code sample trying to convert an empty string? Even changing the result to `null` it still uses the default value of `"0"`...

Comment: @Phill: Please read my comment again - and the previous comments. un-lucky claimed that `Convert.ToInt32` couldn't handle a null reference. I said it could, but that it couldn't handle an empty string. You then addressed a comment to me saying "it handles an empty string fine" apparently missing the context that it's `Convert.ToInt32` that can't handle an empty string... and then not reading my explanation at 09:39:13Z.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh FFS, someone has their name as 'un-lucky' this is another reason why we should use proper names. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @HarshBaid Which version of Sitecore are you using and which namespace is `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty()`, I couldn't find that method.   You could use the Sitecore GetInt util method which will int.TryParse else return the default value: `var userId = Sitecore.MainUtil.GetInt(SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty("UserId"), 0)`

Comment: @jammykam I'm using `Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140228)` and `SecurityUtil` it is not part of Sitecore but it is based on Sitecore RuntimeSettings. I'm using `Sitecore.Context.User.RuntimeSettings.Properties` in method `GetUserProperty`

Comment: @JonSkeet based on this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870624/468718) I think I need to change ternary `?:` operator to `if-else` block

Comment: I found the issue. It was indeed `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty` that returned incorrect value. Thanks for supporting in this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty(propertyName)` is returning a value that cannot be parsed into an int.

modify `SomeMethod()` like this

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
  int userId = 0;
  string userProperty = GetUserProperty("UserId", "0");

  if(int.TryParse(userProperty , out userId)){
      // Do something with userId..
  }
  else{
    //Do something with the exception
      //Console.Write("Invalid property value {0}", userProperty);
//Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Invalid property value " + userProperty.ToString(), this);
  }
}
```

Comment: `int userId 0;` should be `int userId = 0;` actually.That's a typo.

Comment: Change Console.Write with Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Invalid property value " + userProperty.ToString(), this); as this question is related with Sitecore. And Sitecore is web site and doesn't work with console.

Comment: I found the issue. It was indeed `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty` that returned incorrect value. Thanks for supporting in this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to an world where not everyone shares the same alphabet.

`CurrentCulture` is probably the UI culture in your case and therefore unreliable. It might be f.ex. chinese depending on your user :-)

The better way to handle this is to explicitly set the culture.

```
int value;
if (!int.TryParse(GetUserProperty("UserId", "0"), 
    NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
{
   // make / throw your own error message with details on the user property!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your method like this:

```
public string GetUserProperty(string propertyName, string defaultValue = "")
{
    var propertyValue = SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty(propertyName);
    return Array.TrueForAll(propertyValue .ToCharArray(), c => Char.IsDigit(c)) ? propertyValue : defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very probably it's the GetUserPropery which returns an invalid integer.
Try this ( if your value can be like 23.5, use a Regex instead to validate the string ):

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var userIdStr =GetUserProperty("UserId", "0");
    Debug.Assert(userIdStr.All(char.IsDigit));
    var userId = Convert.ToInt32(userIdStr);
    // Do something with userId..
}
```

Or put a breakpoint with a Condition using Int.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

The error cause is the `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty()` method, because maybe its not convertible to `Convert.ToInt32()`.

```
public string GetUserProperty(string propertyName, string defaultValue = "")
{
    var propertyValue = SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty(propertyName); // Why used var maybe because its not convertible to integer?
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue) ? propertyValue : defaultValue; // If this is true and propertyValue is not convertible to Int32, System.FormateException will be occurred.
}
```

Just like example in my fiddle: http://goo.gl/GMP5tH

Comment: I found the issue. It was indeed `SecurityUtil.GetUserProperty` that returned incorrect value. Thanks for supporting in this.

Comment: @HarshBaid Nice to know :D